# Evaluating the Gamma function integral for an arbitrary value.

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions

How do you compute this integral?

$$\Gamma(\alpha ) =\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{\alpha -1}dx$$

I tried doing integration by parts but it continued to repeat.

Comment: You have to add restrictions to $\alpha$ for it the integration by parts to terminate.

Comment: There is no analytic form for this but there are some partial results. If $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$ then there is a closed formula. If you expand $e^{-x}$ by its power series, then you can integrate term by term and find a "closed" formula.

Comment: If you could compute it for arbitrate $\alpha$ then we wouldn't need the Gamma function.

Comment: @Basti There is no known closed formula for $\Gamma(1/4)$ using elementary functions, for example. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function

Answer (score 1):

Let **$$I =\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{\alpha -1}dx$$**
now, when you integrate by part taking $x^{a-1}$ to be second function and $e^{-x}$ first function you get,

$I= -x^{a-1}e^{-x} + \frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{a}e^{-x}dx$ 
now

$I= -x^{a-1}e^{-x} + \frac{1}{a}[(a-1)x^{a-1}e^{-x} + (a-1)\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{a-1}e^{-x}dx]$
so we can write this as

$I= -x^{a-1}e^{-x} + \frac{1}{a}[(a-1)x^{a-1}e^{-x} + (a-1)I]$
Now I think you can continue from here.

Comment: Your first line doesn't make sense. The letter $x$ is a dummy variable here.

Comment: @user49640 I mean that we have to take $e^{-x}$ first function which will be differentiated and second one will be integrated using integration by parts, sorry forgot to write "function" there, just typing mistake. I am new so trying to do less mistake while typing, writing in LeTex makes me tired.

Comment: I understand, but $I$ is supposed to be a number, not a function of $x$. In any case, there must be a mistake somewhere, because there is no closed form for the integral of $x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-x}$ when $\alpha$ isn't an integer. If you think you have an antiderivative, then please check it by differentiating.

Comment: @user49640 here I used "I" as a sign to represent integration, and yes I did it for the case when a isn't variable, I thought it might give OP the idea how to solve question when integration repeats itself, I think that's where OP is having problem so I represent integration using "I" so he can take it to other side and will be able to solve problem, since question doesn't states is "a" is variable or integer.

Comment: I have two problems with what you wrote. The first is that you don't distinguish between definite and indefinite integrals – you combine the two in a way that is incorrect. The second problem is that there must be a mistake in your antiderivative of $x^{a - 1} e^{-x}$.